# MySQL query, add new alias

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query using for search script and i need to add another field (like SPV.term alias) This code is tell me an Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'S.id' in 'on clause'.

```
$query = "
SELECT
  SP.url,
  SP.id,
  S.name,
  SP.hit,
  SP.hot,
  SP.action,
  SP.id,
  SP.smallimage,
  SP.mainmodimage,
  (SELECT
     stock
   FROM shop_product_variants
   WHERE shop_product_variants.product_id = S.id
       AND stock > 0
   LIMIT 1) as stock,
  (SELECT
     price
   FROM shop_product_variants
   WHERE shop_product_variants.product_id = S.id
    OR shop_product_variants.product_id = S.id
       AND stock = 0
   LIMIT 1) as price,
  (SELECT
     id
   FROM shop_product_variants
   WHERE shop_product_variants.product_id = S.id
    OR shop_product_variants.product_id = S.id
       AND stock = 0
   LIMIT 1) as v_id,
  (SELECT
     old_price
   FROM shop_product_variants
   WHERE shop_product_variants.product_id = S.id
       AND stock > 0
   LIMIT 1) as old_price
FROM shop_products_i18n S,
  shop_product_variants SPV
  INNER JOIN shop_products SP
    ON SP.id = S.id
WHERE SP.active = 1
    AND S.name LIKE '%" . $get . "%'
     OR SP.url LIKE '%" . $get . "%'
     OR SPV.term LIKE '%" . $get . "%'
GROUP BY S.id
ORDER BY stock DESC
";
```

Comment: This line's silly isn't it?      , (SELECT price FROM shop_product_variants WHERE shop_product_variants.product_id = S.id OR shop_product_variants.product_id = S.id AND stock = 0 LIMIT 1) as price

Comment: ... and don't mix implicit (comma-) and explicit JOIN syntax. In fact, don't use implicit joins at all!

Comment: ...and let's hope no one 'gets' anything nasty! http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: How can i add 'term' field from shop_product_variants table?

Comment: Well, if it was me, I'd provide proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT, and take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `from` clause:

```
FROM shop_products_i18n S,
     shop_product_variants SPV INNER JOIN
     shop_products SP
     ON SP.id = S.id
```

The problem is that you are mixing old-style joins and new-style joins.  A simple rule:  Never use a commas in the `from` clause.

I think you really mean:

```
FROM shop_products_i18n S INNER JOIN
     shop_products SP
     ON SP.id = S.id
```

Because you don't use `SPV` anywhere else in the outer query, except for the `where` clause.  That condition should probably go into each of the subqueries.

By the way, you can fix the original problem by replacing the `,` with `cross join`:

```
FROM shop_products_i18n S CROSS JOIN
     shop_product_variants SPV INNER JOIN
     shop_products SP
     ON SP.id = S.id
```

Although `,` and `cross join` both perform cartesian products, they behave differently in the `FROM` clause in terms of precedence.  The problem that you have with the `,` is that the precedence rules say the following `INNER JOIN` is parsed first -- so the columns in `S` are not available.

Comment: When i replace `,` with `cross join`, my script hangs :(

Comment: @user2807350 . . . At least it parses.  As I say in the answer, you don't really want a `cross join` there.  Just fix the query as I describe.

Comment: I need to add alias `SPV.term` here `OR SPV.term LIKE '%" . $get . "%'` to perform search in this field.

Comment: @user2807350 . . . Add it to each of the subqueries, which is probably where you really need it.  Otherwise, put in the correct `join` conditions.